# SQL Server reporting services shutting down without log info

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, service, windows-service, ssrs

Using SQL Server 2008 Reporting services.  Finding that the service is shutdown without anything in the windows event log or in SQL Server events.  I see the log entry for the service starting when I manually start it, but nothing for the shutdown or errors.  Windows or SQL server are NOT being restarted when this happens.  The service is set to start automatically and to restart upon failure (which is not happening).

Any help in next steps for troubleshooting/fixing would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does it ever actually start?

Comment: @squillman - it starts just fine when I start it.  Trying to figure out why it is dieing.  It will run fine for days and then I'll get a call from a user that it's down with no logging information to troubleshoot why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some additional logs for reporting services located at:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles\

You may be able to find some additional hints why the service is dieing in the first place.